What purpose does `proxy_set_header Host $host` do in nginx?
The $host variable in NGINX contains the value of the Host header from the client's original HTTP request. When you use proxy_set_header Host $host;, you're essentially setting the Host header in the request being sent to the backend server to the same value as the Host header in the client's request.
This is a frequent flag set, but I don't understand what it achieves. When using a proxy server such a nginx, if all we're doing is forwarding a received request and nothing is being changed, what purpose does this configuration achieve achieve? When we receive a request and we do not set this, is the HOST not set?
